# Split string and validate each part

Tags: c#, winforms, split

I have a file that contains content in a pipe delimited format.  This is in C# in a WinForm application.

Example of Perfect format:

```
1000|2014|01|AP|1|00000001|00
```

- 1st value should always be 4 length.
- 2nd value - 4 length.
- 3rd value - 2 length.
- 4th value - 2 length.
- 5th value - 1 length.
- 6th value - 8 length.
- 7th value - 2 length.

Example of typical format that is received:

```
1000|2014|1|AP|1|1
```

Notice that the typical format does not include the 7th value.  In these cases, it should be defaulted to "00".  The other fields are not padded with leading zeroes either.  Here is my approach.

```
//string buildcontentfromfile = the contents of each file that I receive and read
char[] delimiter = new char[] {'|'};
string[] contents = buildcontentfromfile.Split(delimiter);

if(contents[0].Length == 4)
{
   if(contents[1].Length == 4)
   {
      if(contents[2].Length == 2)
      {
         if(contents[3].Length == 2)
         {
            if(contents[4].Length == 1)
            {
               if(contents[5].Length == 8)
               {
                  if(contents[6].Length == 2)
                  {
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This would take care of the "Perfect format" and of course I will need to add more logic to address the "Typical format" of how they are received, like checking for the 7th value, and add the leading 0s into the fields that need them, and the length.  But am I even approaching this the right way?  Is there a more simpler process to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: go with sub strings perhaps?

Comment: I would look at using Regular Expressions. They are great at evaluating character types and lengths of parts of a string.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thanks for your inputs.  I think I will try out the Regular Expressions tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
var re = new Regex("\d{4}\|\d{4}\|\d\d\|\w\w\|\d\|\d{8}\|\d\d");
var valid = re.IsMatch(input);
```

Comment: Explanation: \d = number, \w = alfanumeric character, \| = pipe character, {x} = last token x exactly times

Comment: Thanks for the explain.  I will give this a try tomorrow and hope it works for what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Just from the top of my head (I haven't tried this on an actual machine)

```
var input = "1000|2014|01|AP|1|00000001|00";

var pattern = new int[] {4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 8, 2};

// Check each element length according to it's input position.
var matches = input
     .Split('|')
      // Get only those elements that satisfy the length condition.
     .Where((x, index) => x.Count() == pattern(index))
     .Count();

if (matches == pattern.Count())
    // Input was as expected.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I will try the regular expression first, but if i cannot get it to work, then I will give your suggestion a run.